# Load JS function inside a div

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple span and I want to show full date from Javascript inside this span. I'm not getting how to do it.

**HTML (The date would be in place of the "..."):**

```
<h3>Data Atual: </h3><span id="date" onload="newDate()">...</span>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function newDate() {
    var dateBox = document.getElementById('date');
    dateBox.innerHTML = '';

    var date = new Date();

    var newDate = date.getDay + ', ' + date.getDate + ' de ' + date.getMonth + ', ' + date.getFullYear + '.';

    dateBox.innerHTML += newDate;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Spans don't have a `load` event. That event only exists on the body and elements that load their data from an external URL, such as `img` and `iframe`.

Answer (score 1):

The `load` event doesn't fire on static HTML elements, only elements that load their data asynchronously from an external URL.

Put the call in the body's `onload` event.

```
<body onload="newDate()">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to show the complete day in your span text:

```
document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = createNewDate();

function createNewDate() {
    const date = new Date();
    const newDate = date.getDay + ', ' + date.getDate + ' de ' + date.getMonth + ', ' + date.getFullYear + '.';
    return newDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

do not need to load it on start. Actually you are using get dates wrongly. This following code will solve it your problem. Put it before `</body>`

```
<script>
  var date = new Date();
  var newDate = date.getDay() + ', ' + date.getDate() + ' de ' + date.getMonth() + ', ' + date.getFullYear() + '.';    
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = newDate;
</script>
```